# Javascript method declaration

Tags: javascript

Is it right to declare a method like this?

```
window['TEST']['myfunction?'] = function(param) {
        for(var a in([ param.getElementsByTagName('ol'), param.getElementsByTagName('ul') ]){
found += a.length();
}
        return a != 0
            ? true
            : false;
    }
```

I always use to declare method like this

```
var TEST = function(param){
...
}
```

But I saw the first declaration in some code. But I am not able to get that. What's the difference in these two type of declaration. Which one is more efficient?

Comment: First declaration is bad. 1. Global 2. Using `?` in function name

Comment: You have two completely unrelated questions there. Please pick one of them to ask about.

Comment: I actually dont know the syntax about 1st declartion . I just it somewhere. I want to know about the first declartion syntax. Is there any link for that?

Comment: @Quentin I have changed. So now can I know about the question

Comment: I just don'tr know why this question is marked negative? Its simple syntax question then whats the prob in this. And also who are voting it down , must also comment for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Javascript, virtually everything is an object meaning that everything has a certain set of properties. You can access or set these properties in a few ways, two of which are relevant here.

The first option is `window.foo = 'bar';`. Another way to write this would be `window['foo'] = 'bar';` The first one is called *dot notation*, the second one is called *bracket notation*. Bracket notation has one advantage over dot notation, which is the type of characters you can use. For example `window.invalid-foo = 'bar'` will not work. `window['invalid-foo']` on the other hand does.

Now to get to your question; there is a possibility that when encountering `window['TEST']['myFunction?']` the original author of the code has his own framework that checks the global `window.TEST` object for functions. And iterates through these functions and calls them as way of testing his code.

I would not recommend doing things this way because:

1. [you're polluting the global namespace.](http://lillylabs.no/2014/09/19/avoid-polluting-the-global-namespace-in-javascript/)
2. You're creating unnecessary confusion by using a non-standard approach to declaring variables.

Is one way of declaring functions faster than the other? The latter is faster by an [enormous amount.](http://jsperf.com/declaring-variables-vs-setting-them-on-window) We're talking 2 million operations per second versus 1.5 billion operations per second.

[image: test result]

Comment: Nice explanation. But what if i have given the name as in the question so `window['TEST']['myFunction?']` ., now how can i call this method ?

Comment: `window['TEST']['myFunction?'](param)`

Comment: If I try `TEST.myfunction?(param)`, that will give error?

Comment: Yes, because you can't use special characters when using dot notation. For example, it would be impossible for the interpreter to properly interpret both `var a = test ? 1 : 2` and `var a = test?() ? 1 : 2;`.

Comment: That helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`window['TEST']['myfunction?'] =` takes the global object, gets the object stored in its `TEST` property, and then assigns a function to its `myfunction?` property.

Globals and property names with odd characters (like `?`) are both generally best avoided.

`var TEST =` declares a locally scoped variable (`TEST`) and assigns a value to it. Since it isn't a property of an object, it isn't a method.

Comment: Okay , so if I want to call method declared as 1st type (Globally) with parameter , then what should be the syntax? `Test.myfunction?(param)`

Comment: `window['TEST']['myfunction?'](param)`

Comment: `var test` placed outside a function will be globally scoped. Variable scope is dependent on where you declare the variable. Inside a function and it is scoped to the function, outside and it is global. Excluding the `var` token and it is always global. `test = 0;` is always global if it has not yet been declared. Not allowed in strict mode `"use strict"`

Answer (score 1):

Bracket notation and dot notation are interchangeable. As far as I know they execute at about the same speed. Bracket notation does allow you to use characters that are illegal in dot notation.

```
// eg 
var myObject = {}
myObject["var1"] = 1; // bracket notation same as dot notation
myObject.var1 = 1;    // dot notation same as bracket notation

myObject["test-me"] = 2; // valid creation of property test-me
myObject.test-me = 2; // will throw an error as "-" is an operator.
// the invalid character will force you to use bracket notion whenever you access the property.
```

Someone else can answer the second part.

Comment: Thanks for that , what about declaring it with window[] ,i guess that makes it global?

Comment: window is the default global scope for most browser environments.